# How to get the crash log file for Lightworks?

Tags: bug-reporting, lightworks

So I got beta access to lightworks and It crashes a lot sadly I can not get terminal output 
[image]
is there a way to get software crash log file ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well different applications have different logging systems. There's no one central log that contains all the output from all the programs that run on your system.So basically it depends on the application.

The crash reports are generally stored in `/var/crash/`.But not all programs crash reports need not be present,it depends on whether the application wishes to store it.

For lightwork, according to their [website](http://lightworkmarking.org/frequentlyAskedQuestions.asp#wdifh) the Lightwork log files, called **lightwork.log** and **lightwork.log.1**; you will find these files in the following location: Linux: `\home\your_user_name` .

Comment: Is there a way to get for example lightworks log file ????

Comment: Im not sure but according to their [website](http://lightworkmarking.org/frequentlyAskedQuestions.asp#wdifh) the Lightwork log files, called **lightwork.log** and **lightwork.log.1**; you will find these files in the following location:   Linux: `\home\your_user_name` .